# list of char* to vector of strings

Tags: c++

it looks like when I cout *cp, it only outputs the first letter of the string and after I put them in vector, my output is blank. what am I doing wrong?

```
//write a program to assign the elements from a list of char* pointers to c-style character strings to a vector of strings
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main ()
{
    list<const char*> clist;
    cout<<"please enter a string"<<endl;
    for(string s; getline(cin,s); )
    {   
        const char* cp=s.c_str();
        clist.push_back(cp);
        cout<<*cp;
    }
    cout<<*clist.begin();
    vector<string> svec;
    svec.assign(clist.begin(),clist.end());
    for(vector<string>::iterator iter=svec.begin(); iter!=svec.end(); ++iter)
        cout<<*iter<<endl;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com instead of tagging. Although this isn't really a CR question.

Comment: `cout<<*cp;`, when you dereference the `cp` variable (using the `*` operator), you get a single char from your string. Therefore, in order to print the entire string, you have to pass the actual pointer, e.g: `cout << cp;`. Yet, you should use `std::string` rather than *naked pointers*.

Comment: What gave you the idea that you should use pointers? If you're new to C++, you might like to consider this pseudo-rule: "If you're using a pointer, you're Doing It Wrong."

Comment: You are also copying the internal pointer of the string and not making a full copy when you push back into clist. The pointer you have in there won't be valid after the next loop since you read back into s again, possibly reallocating that buffer.

Answer (score 6):

This will print the whole string:

```
cout << cp;  // You're providing cout a const char *
```

This will only print one character:

```
cout << *cp; // You're providing cout a char
```

As to what's wrong with your vector, you're only storing pointers to strings, not strings themselves.  The memory for the string has gone out of scope.  As others have said, use `std::string` instead of raw `const char *`.

Comment: oh right. what about the bottom part where I want to assign char*'s to a vector of strings

Comment: I want to just use strings. it's just a question in the book. I am trying to figure out how to assign a list of char*'s to a vector of strings.

Answer (score 4):

> cout *cp, it only outputs the first letter of the string

Well, `*cp` is a character (the one found at the location to which the pointer `cp` pointers). So, yea, it will.

> after I put them in vector, my output is blank

It's unfortunate that your program did not crash outright, as the pointers in your list become dangling pointers almost as soon as you store them.

Store `std::string`s from the very start.

Comment: I want to have a list of char* first, then assign those c-style strings to a vector of string

Comment: @ihm: Why? That's ridiculous. Don't do that.

Comment: why they become dangling? I am sorry if it's bothering.

Comment: yeah, I got it. they point to the local string s. every loops reset s and pointers become dangling.

Comment: @ihm: Correct. :) Storing pointers in C++ containers is usually a sign of a design flaw; you're already using `std::list`, so use `std::string` whilst you're at it!

Answer (score 2):

```
cout<<*cp;
```

will output a single character because it points to a `const char *`

You need to do:

```
cout<<cp;
```

This will output the entire string pointed by `cp`.

Answer (score 1):

> it looks like when I cout *cp, it only outputs the first letter of the string

`*cp` *is* the first letter of the string. `cout << cp` will print the whole string.

> after I put them in vector, my output is blank.

Your list contains pointers to the contents of `s`, which is only valid within the body of the loop. Once the string goes out of scope, the pointer is "dangling" - pointing to deallocated memory. Trying to use the pointer will give undefined behaviour.

You'll need to keep hold of a copy of the string itself, either by making `clist` a `list<string>`, or by keeping the strings in another container, and storing pointers to the data in that container in `clist`.

Alternatively, you could use string literals rather than reading strings from `cin`. String literals live as long as the program, so there are no issues with dangling pointers.

(That's assuming that the comment in the first line of your code is a specification that you can't change. Otherwise, I'd get rid of `clist` completely, and push each string onto the back of `svec` as I read it. It's rarely a good idea to use pointers for anything.)

Comment: it's not a homework. I am reading a book and this is a question in the book. I see why they become dangling now. beside having another container of strings and having pointers point to each of them. is there any better way? if it's possible

Comment: @ihm: you could use string literals rather than reading the strings from `cin`: `clist.push_back("Hello!");` will work, with no dangling pointer issues. But if you need to create and keep hold of a bunch of strings, there's nothing better than a container of strings.

Comment: thanks. it's very helpful. btw. what's a good txt editor for writing code in linux? I am using gedit. but it becomes really slow for some reason.

Comment: @ihm: I've not found any good enough to recommend. I mostly use vim, gedit and eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple big problems here.  First of all,

```
const char* cp=s.c_str();
```

returns a pointer to an internal member string within std::string.  When you change the string, the value referenced by the returned pointer to c_str may be changed (may even be in a new location).  So, the values in your list are not valid.  Make sure you don't use c_str and try to make use of the result after the original string has been changed (unless you copy the c_str result into a new char array.

Also,

```
cout<<*cp;
```

only prints our your first element.  Get rid of the * to print the whole c-string at that list element.